# How to access Metasploitable2 vm frrom a Kali vm?

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

I am just starting to learn Metasploit and trying to practice on a metasploitable2 instance. My host system is Ubuntu and I have 2 virtual machines set up in VMware Player. The first one has Kali 2.0 installed and is running in bridged mode. The second has Metasploitable2 installed and is running in host-only mode. My problem is that I can't access the Metasploitable2 vm from the Kali vm. This makes sense cause it is in host-only mode and thus can only be accessed from my Host os (ubuntu).

I was following the Metasploit-unleashed guide and they state that the metasploitable2 vm should only be run in host-only or NAT mode but I have tried pinging the metasploitable2 ip from kali in both modes with no response. How should I be setting this lab up? Thanks.

Comment: This is neither a kali question nor a metasploitable question: this is a pure VMware networking question.

Comment: Thanks for migrating it. I added those tags in case the problem was software specific, but I realized after that the simple solution was simply putting both the vm's into Host-only mode like Iszi suggested. Both of the vm's are on the same network as the host system now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget the exact terminology, and it varies anyway between virtualization platforms, but you should be able to configure a virtual network that only guest machines can connect to. That's what your Metasploitable VM should be attached to always. The Kali VM should be connected only to the bridged adapter when needing to get online for updates/research etc. Then disconnect the bridged adapter and connect the Kali VM to just the virtual network when you're ready to actually attack the Metasploitable system. It's generally best to not have the Kali system connected to both at once.

Comment: Oh good idea! I was thinking of doing something along this line after I posted this question. I am using VMware Player btw. Now to figure out how to configure these adapters...